# Does Scala have a library method to build Option-s that takes into account empty strings?

Tags: scala

I want to filter out empty strings to put them into an Option. So I quickly built this now:

```
def StrictOption(s: String) = s match {
  case s if s != null && s.trim.length() > 0 => Some(s)
  case _ => None
}
```

Question: is this maybe already somewhere in the standard library?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I don't think there's *one single method* in the standard library to do this, but you can do this much more tersely than your implementation.

```
Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: I would even use `Option(s).map(_.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty)` one-liner to trim extra spaces.

Comment: `Option(s.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Comment: @RomanKazanovskyi, that is risky if `s` comes from a java-world and could be `null`

Comment: yes, then better `Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)`

Comment: @jan it is safe: 

`val toStr : String => Option[String] = s => Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)`
and then call it:
`toStr(null) //res1: Option[String] = None`

Comment: @RomanKazanovskyi, sure the answer is safe. I was referring to your variant: `Option(s.trim)` this will fail if `s` is `null`, wouldn’t it?

Comment: @AlexanderProkofyev you don't need `.map(_.trim)` as trim method should never return a null

Answer (score 9):

If you care at all about performance then

```
if (s.trim.isEmpty) None else Some(s)
```

is only 4 characters longer than Ben James's solution, and runs 3 times faster, in my benchmark (47 vs 141).

Comment: This causes a NullPointerException for s == null.

Comment: @mkneissl `null` should not need to be a consideration in Scala, but if it is, you could change it to `if (s == null || s.trim.isEmpty)`. The run time is exactly the same.

Comment: See the Question, null seems to matter to the OP. Otherwise I 99% agree.

Comment: Unfortunately in Spark Dataframes, `null` is a value you have to account for.

Comment: It's also something to consider in a lot of java interop.

Comment: And, if `s` is a function call, this becomes even less applicable.

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, for those not expecting `null`s (non-Java context), [`Option::unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) and [`Option::when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) are now an alternative option:

```
// val str = "hello"
Option.unless(str.isEmpty)(str)
// Option[String] = Some(hello)
Option.when(str.nonEmpty)(str)
// Option[String] = Some(hello)

// val str: String = ""
Option.unless(str.isEmpty)(str)
// Option[String] = None
Option.when(str.nonEmpty)(str)
// Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing built in; Ben's filter is the best brief version if performance isn't an issue (e.g. you're validating user input).  Typically, performance will not be an issue.

Also, note that it's a little strange to use `match` when you're not actually matching anything; it's just more boilerplate to get an if-else statement.  Just say

```
if (s ne null && s.trim.length > 0) Some(s) else None
```

which is about as fast and brief as anything, unless you want to write your own is-it-whitespace method.  Note that `trim` uses a peculiar criterion: anything above \u0020 (i.e. ' ') is not trimmed, and anything equal or below is.  So you could also write your own trimmed-string-is-empty detector, if performance of this operation was particularly important:

```
def ContentOption(s: String): Option[String] = {
  if (s ne null) {
    var i = s.length-1
    while (i >= 0) {
      if (s.charAt(i) > ' ') return Some(s)
      i -= 1
    }
  }
  None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be achieved with a for-comprehension

```
val res = for (v <- Option(s) if s.nonEmpty) yield v
```

Answer (score -2):

Option("something") produces Some("something")

Option(null) produces None